# How to keep row color when move row JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

How can I keep the row color when I move a row in `JTable` Swing? Here is my code I move the row direct in the table model.

```
void moveRow(int row, int direction){ // direction in {-1, 1}
      direction += row;
      DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
      Object obj1 = model.getRow(row);
      Object obj2 = model.getRow(direction);

     model.setRow(row, obj2);
     model.setRow(direction, obj1);
     table.setRowSelectionInterval(direction, direction);
}
```

Comment: How you set the row color?